# Number Of SOQL Queries 100 After Single Query In New Unit Test Method

Tags: apex, unit-test, governorlimits

In the below unit test my debug line

`System.debug('+++ Number of Queries used in this apex code 2.1 so far: ' + Limits.getQueries());`

shows that the number of queries after my single query, in a new method, is 100. My understanding was that each method is has it's own set of limits (although I can't find the documentation to confirm this), in which case shouldn't the number of queries should be 1?

This is causing me to hit the error

> System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

so I'm unable to retrieve the updated records & assert the results of my test.

```
@isTest
public class WE_MRFv3Test {

    @testSetup
    static void dataSetup() {

        User u = WE_TestDataUtility.createStandardUser();

        System.runas(u) {

            VApexC__c acCS = WE_TestDataUtility.createApexControllerCustSett(
                'Opportunity MRF',  // fieldRef
                false);             // fcstDisabledStatus

            acCS.BudgetManagerDisabled__c = true;

            insert acCS;

            VProfileId__c profCS = WE_TestDataUtility.createProfileIdCustSett(
                'User',                 // locationRef
                'System Admin User',    // fieldRef
                true);                  // settingStatus

            profCS.Team_Name__c = 'Virtual Admin';

            insert profCS;

            VRTN__c rtCS = WE_TestDataUtility.createRecTypeNameCustSett(
                'CP Virtual Prepaid MC',    // rtName
                'NAEU Opps');               // csField

            rtCS.Product_Name__c = 'Virtual Prepaid MasterCard';

            insert rtCS;

            List<Target__c> targets = WE_TestDataUtility.createTargets(
                2,                                  // noMonths
                u.Id,                               // salespersonId
                date.today().addMonths(1).year(),   // firstYear
                date.today().addMonths(1).month(),  // firstMonth
                'Virtual Sales EU',                 // team
                'Close Date',                       // dateType
                100000);                            // target

            insert targets;

            List<Budget__c> budgets = new List<Budget__c>();

            for(integer i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                budgets.add(new Budget__c(
                    Name = 'Test Budget ' + i,
                    Date__c = date.today().addMonths(i),
                    Team__c = 'Virtual Admin',
                    Product__c = 'Virtual Prepaid MasterCard',
                    Budget__c = 1));
            }
            insert budgets;

            List<Opportunity> oppsToInsert = new List<Opportunity>();

            List<Opportunity> opportunities0 = WE_TestDataUtility.createOpportunities(
                'EU Opps',                          // oppRef
                1,                                  // noOpps
                'CP Virtual Prepaid MC',            // recordTypeName
                'id0',                              // identifier
                '1) Suspect',                       // stageName
                date.today().addmonths(1),          // closeDate
                'Standard',                         // rampProfile
                100.00);                            // settlement

            insert opportunities0;

            acCS.BudgetManagerDisabled__c = false;
            update acCS;

            List<Opportunity> opportunities1 = WE_TestDataUtility.createOpportunities(
                'EU Opps',                          // oppRef
                1,                                  // noOpps
                'CP Virtual Prepaid MC',            // recordTypeName
                'id1',                              // identifier
                '1) Suspect',                       // stageName
                date.today().addmonths(1),          // closeDate
                'Standard',                         // rampProfile
                100.00);                            // settlement

            oppsToInsert.addAll(opportunities1);

            List<Opportunity> cappedFcstDurOpps = WE_TestDataUtility.createOpportunities(
                'EU Opps',                          // oppRef
                1,                              // noOpps
                'CP Virtual Prepaid MC',        // recordTypeName
                'id2',                          // identifier
                '1) Suspect',                   // stageName
                date.today().addMonths(1),      // closeDate
                'Standard',                     // rampProfile
                100.00);                        // settlement

            for(Opportunity o : cappedFcstDurOpps) {
                o.FSR_End_Date__c = date.today().addMonths(9);
                oppsToInsert.add(o);
            }

            insert oppsToInsert;
        }
    }

    static testMethod void testMrfUpdates2() {

        List<Opportunity> opportunities1 = [SELECT Id, CloseDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE '%Id1%'];

        System.debug('+++ Number of Queries used in this apex code 2.1 so far: ' + Limits.getQueries());

        test.startTest();

        for(Opportunity upOppsFcstAdj : opportunities1) {
            upOppsFcstAdj.Forecast_Adjustment__c = 10;
        }
        update opportunities1;

        for(Opportunity upOppsRampProfile : opportunities1) {
            upOppsRampProfile.FSR_End_Date__c = upOppsRampProfile.CloseDate.addMonths(6);
        }
        update opportunities1;

        test.stopTest();

        System.debug('+++ Number of Queries used in this apex code 2.2 so far: ' + Limits.getQueries());

        // too many queries error on next line
        List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c > mrfRecs1 = [SELECT Id, Budget__c
                                                       FROM Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c 
                                                       WHERE Opportunity__c IN :opportunities1];

        // 1 is noOpps
        system.assertEquals(1*3, mrfRecs1.size(), 'there should be 3 MRF records for each Opportunity, as the forecast duration is capped');
        system.assert(mrfRecs1[0].Budget__c != null, 'budget should have been matched with MRF record');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your org has events that are triggered from dml statements during @testSetup (which you likely do), THEN any DML or SOQL statement that results from those events are counted outside the context of @testSetup, in the test's other methods. So this will impact the overall governing limits for your test class.

Check this thread for more information related to [limits & @TestSetup](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73129/how-do-governing-limits-work-with-testsetup-from-spring-15-release)

Comment: I'm hitting the limit outside startTest stopTest not within that context.

Comment: In that case when you insert the record your trigger is running which is causing this error. Check your triggers

Comment: The question I'm asking is why am I at 100 queries having just entered a new method and executed one query?

Comment: As I mentioned your trigger also running and if they are doing any SOQL that will also count in this limit.

Comment: If you look at the location of my debug line, you'll see that I've not executed any transactions in my method before I check the limits.

Comment: @AlexS check this thred [TestSetup](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73129/how-do-governing-limits-work-with-testsetup-from-spring-15-release)

Comment: check triggers.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, the post that you sent me a link to explains it. If you'd like to update your answer, I'll accept it.