# How Many @TestSetup annotated methods are allowed per class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

How many setup methods are allowed in 1 test class? [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm#!) says only 1 but I am able to add 4 and save to salesforce and run test successfully.

> - You can have only one test setup method per test class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with **`API Version 39.0`**, you can only have one method per class with the `@TestSetup` annotation. Saving with a lower API Version will for example allow you to compile this class:

```
@IsTest
class DemoTests
{
    @TestSetup static void setup1() { }
    @TestSetup static void setup2() { }
}
```

But saving with the more recent versions will yield this error:

> Only one method per type can be defined with: TestSetup

In the lower versions, there does not appear to be any limit in place. I stopped checking at 1011.

```
@IsTest
class DemoTests
{ // compiles below API Version 39.0
    @TestSetup static void setup1() { }
    @TestSetup static void setup2() { }
    @TestSetup static void setup3() { }
    //...
    @TestSetup static void setup1010() { }
    @TestSetup static void setup1011() { }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good to know. I completely missed the change notes on limiting test classes to one `@testSetup` annotated method. Out of curiosity, how many iterations did it take for you to arrive at 1011? Unless you had a script running that, it'd have to be a pretty slow day to increase the methods one per iteration.

Comment: I started off adding a few score at a time, then beyond a hundred started adding a couple hundred at a time.

Comment: Cool! I remember you and I had posts on a same [topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163568/how-to-use-the-annotated-testsetup-method-in-tests/163578#163578) not too long ago, and then it was all legal to have more than one `@testSetup` methods in single test class.

Comment: Guess, I need to update that post. :-D

Comment: There' was never any guarantee that multiple `@testSetup` methods would execute in any particular order. That might be a driver behind "Only one method per type..." in version 39

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_load_data.htm seems to be a better option.What do you think:)