# @testSetup vs DataFactory?

Tags: apex, unit-test, bestpractice, test-setup

When testing, how/when will `@TestSetup` annotation be preferable to a "DataFactory"?

I understand how both works, but I don't see any case where I'd rather use the `@testSetup` annotation.

I use [this datafactory](https://github.com/dhoechst/Salesforce-Test-Factory) and it works very well.

Comment: avinash's answer is more to the point.  @testSetup and a dataFactory are not mutually exclusive.  They can (and should) be used together more times than not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A major reason to use `@TestSetup` is the situation where you have many tests that require the same baseline of data. The `@TestSetup` method runs once and all its data is available to all the test methods in the class. Any changes made by a test method are rolled back but the `@TestSetup` data isn't. The benefit is faster test running because the baseline data inserts are only done once per test *class* not once per *test* method.

A downside is that the only way to get references to the data created in `@TestSetup` is to query for it. But those queries are much cheaper than the inserts.

(The `@TestSetup` method also gets its own set of governor limits, so if you have a lot of data setup logic that consumes a big proportion of those, moving it to `@TestSetup` will help.)

I use `@TestSetup` sometimes, and other times, when I want to refer to the test data in the following asserts, use builder classes invoked from each test method so I have references to the test objects without having to do queries.

You can choose to use whatever technique you like to create the SObjects and use that method inside the `@TestStup` method or outside of it.

Some more information on @TestSetup: [What are the advantage of the @testSetUp annotation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160328/what-are-the-advantage-of-the-testsetup-annotation).

Answer (score 14):

I use both. Why would you have to choose one over the other? @testSetup is a way to reduce test execution time by reusing the data created once in all the test methods of a test class.

TestFactory is to reuse same data in multiple test classes.

Ex:

```
@isTest
private class AvinashTest {
    @testSetup
    static void testSetup() {
        Test.startTest();
        Account a = (Account) TestFactory.createSObject(new Account(), true);
        a.Oracle_Cust_Number__c  = '10';
        update a;
        Brand__c b = (Brand__c) TestFactory.createSObject(new Brand__c(), true);
        example_Product__c rocProd = TestDataFactory.getexampleProduct( 'Test Prod', b );
        insert rocProd;
        Contact c = (Contact) TestFactory.createSObject(new Contact(), true);
        Opportunity o = (Opportunity) TestFactory.createSObject(new Opportunity(AccountId=a.Id,StageName='Closed Lost', Channel_Type__c = 'Direct'), true);
        Product2 prod1 = (Product2) TestFactory.createSObject(new Product2(Brand__c=b.Id), true);
        prod1.example_Product__c = rocProd.Id;

        update new User(Service_Provider__c = true, Id = UserInfo.getUserId()); 
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```